# Ricci SCALAR curvature

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, conformal-geometry

Are there any manifolds that have NULL SCALAR curvature but not null ricci curvature tensor? For dim>2, obviously.

Edit: Are there, also, any manifolds of null scalar curvature but ricci curvature not proportional to the metric tensor?

Comment: The product of a constant positive curvature space with a constant negative curvature space, scaled appropriately, should work

Comment: A trivial example $M^n\times N^n$, where $M^n$ is an n-dimensional Einstein manifold with Ric$=\lambda g$ and $N^n$ is an n-dimensional Einstein manifold with Ric$=-\lambda g$.

Comment: The answer to your second question is the same as the answer to the first: if a metric has zero scalar curvature, then its Ricci tensor is proportional to the metric if and only if it's zero.

Comment: In General Relativity there are many examples.  One example is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric